# VideoViewRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'Init'

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-videoview

I need to play  a video in a Xamarin Forms by getting the URL input from the user. I have used plugin.mediamanager.forms.I am getting the following error "'VideoViewRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'Init'... What is the mistake I am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how to init the class:
https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#important-initialize-plugin

Make sure to call Init() in all the native platforms on startup of your app.

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
```